# How to create Javascript executable?

Tags: javascript

I want to create JavaScript exe file. On clicking of exe file, It should open my reactJS web application in web browser.
From JS exe file, I have to pass query param to Web application.
Please help me with code.

Comment: You do understand how Web applications work, do you?

Comment: you can package it as an [Electron app](http://electron.atom.io/).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a shell script to launch the browser with a link to your web application that is on your local machine. You haven't given much details, but in general it's pretty easy.

```
cat > launch.exe
#!/bin/bash
$BROWSER http://localhost

chmod +x launch.exe
./launch.exe
```

Comment: Also state that he *can't* create a **JS exe file**. I assume he expected it to be possible.

Comment: He can create a JavaScript file with the `.exe` extension. He can make it executable easily. The first line would indicate the interpreter to use.

Comment: By interpreter do you mean the Javascript engine? If so, it is already used by the browser to execute JS within the web page itself. Your solution suffices because I presume he meant that he wanted to open directly the web application through a browser by just clicking an executable. +1

Comment: yes, he can execute javascript using a runtime like v8 or spidermonkey typically it would be node.js

Comment: Yup, but that's a different story. All he wanted to do was just create a shortcut to open his web app. :)

Comment: But I want to send query parameters to my web app from JS exe

Comment: @Livintha you could make it send parameters to a NodeJS application which can read  them with process.args (I'm pretty sure)

Answer (score 2):

If this is to be compiled and run on Windows installations only then here's your answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7435xtz6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Java code is different from JavaScript. They might both be Object Oriented Programming (OOP), but JavaScript is specifically a scripting language. Its impossible to make a .exe file out of JavaScript.

Comment: nothing is impossible. You can make  an EXE with machine language that interprets JavaScript, much like a web browser

Answer (score 0):

You should try jsc.exe (under Windows only), NWJS or Electron.

The latest two are surely your best pick.

Edit: I would add [NeutralinoJs](https://neutralino.js.org/) to my previous suggestion.
It's nice, simple and useful.